# Magento 2: Catalog price rule not expiring

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I have created a Catalog price rule with 10% discount and expiry date. Even after the expiry date, I'm still seeing the discount value on the selected category. I tried below things

1. I ensured catalog price is expired.
2. I have set discount percent to 0.
3. I have cleared cache and re indexed twice

Note: I have even deleted the catalog price rule and re-indexed but still discount is showing.

Any suggestion would he helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to one of the catalog price rule condition was set to false. So the discount applied on all other category products. Adding screenshot below, for reference.

[image]